# PHP: Reuseable Object for Persistent SSH Connection

Tags: php, ajax, oop, phpseclib

I have problem with PHP and SSH phpseclib. The block code below is how I initiate the SSH Object and then login using private key to the SSH Server. Everytime I finished submit data via form to SSH server, the page always refresh (POST to _SELF) and run same block code which take almost 30 second to establish and do relogin process to SSH Server. Can I do the initiating process and login just for once in the beginning and reuse the `$ssh` object for the next process (in same page or in other page)?
Note: I failed use PHP Session because PHP Session can't store Object with references.

```
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('my SSH Server IP Address');

$key = new Crypt_RSA();
$key->loadKey(file_get_contents('privatekey.txt'));
if (!$ssh->login('myUserName', $key)) {
exit('Login Failed');
}
```

Comment: You cannot persist/share a resource between different php processes.

Comment: You could use something like RabbitMPQ or PHPDaemon.

Answer (score 0):

You could have an open loop to hold the process open and use [gearman](http://gearman.org/) to speak to the script but there's no chance of doing on a shared server and if you have server admin they won't be too happy with it. Example open loop:

```
while(true) {

}
```